# Foreach Nested loops issue in powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, office365

What I need to do is to compare the Licence attribute associated with each Username from $O365Users with Enabled attribute using the matching Employee ID in $userID (if it exists). With the standard nested ForEach (above) We use this script to help manage our local Active Directory and MSOL (Microsoft Online – Office 365) objects. My question is : I have got an issue related to the foreach loop so same object returns multiple (forever) I want to do it line-by-line for each user

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Import-Module MSOnline

$password = ConvertTo-SecureString 'PASSWORD' -AsPlainText -Force
$LiveCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("username@domain.com", $password)
New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://ps.outlook.com/powershell/ -Credential $LiveCred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection

Connect-MsolService -Credential $Livecred

$O365Users = Get-MsolUser -All
ForEach ($O365User in $O365Users)
{
  $userID = Import-CSV "c:\Export\list.csv"
  $ADuser = Get-ADUser -Filter "EmployeeID -eq $($userID.EmployeeID)" -Properties whenCreated, Enabled, SAMAccountName
  If (($ADUser.Enabled -eq $True) -and ($O365User.isLicensed = $true))
    {

     Get-MsolUSer -UserPrincipalName $ADuser.UserPrincipalName
        Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $ADuser.UserPrincipalName -RemoveLicenses "company:ENTERPRISEPACK"
    }
}
```

CSV file :

```
EmployeeID
52576
1234
8599
```

Comment: you import the same csv every time and you allways read the same value, which you use to get the user... either you have to have an identifier in your csv to match against inside the loop or you just loop through the csv instead of your users

Comment: @Paul thanks so much I have tried different combines no luck please clarify

Comment: @Arbelac - how are you getting list.csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go this should work

```
$userID = Import-Csv "c:\export\list.csv"

foreach ($user in $userID){

    $ADuser = Get-ADUser -Filter "EmployeeId -eq $($user.EmployeeID)" -Properties whenCreated, Enabled, SAMAccountName
    $O365User = Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $ADuser.UserPrincipalName

    if(($ADuser.Enabled -eq $true) -and ($O365User.isLicensed -eq $true)){
        Get-MsolUSer -UserPrincipalName $ADuser.UserPrincipalName
        Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $ADuser.UserPrincipalName -RemoveLicenses "company:ENTERPRISEPACK"
    }

}
```

Regarding the follow-up question on performance (just what i think might increase performance, no warranty and not tested):

```
$userID = Import-Csv "c:\export\list.csv"
$adusers = Get-ADUser -Filter * -properties EmployeeID,whenCreated,Enabled,SAMAccountname
$msolusers = Get-MsolUser -All

foreach ($user in $userID){

$ADuser = $adusers | where {$_.EmployeeID -eq $user.EmployeeID}
$O365User = $msolusers | where {$_.UserPrincipalName -eq $ADuser.UserPrincipalName}

if(($ADuser.Enabled -eq $true) -and ($O365User.isLicensed -eq $true)){
    Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $ADuser.UserPrincipalName -RemoveLicenses "company:ENTERPRISEPACK"
}

}
```

Depending on how many of the AD / MSOL users there are and you have to match this might de- or increase the execution time, you will have to test since i cant.
I also removed the get-msoluser in your if statement since it´s only function is generating (unnecessary?) output. If there are any problems with my "improvements" let me know and we can see what we can do ;)

Comment: thanks so much for your help its works very well Last question :  it takes some time to process how can I tune this script?

Comment: thanks again man I have used measure-command. its happened performance increase

Answer (score -1):

Please try:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Import-Module MSOnline

$password = ConvertTo-SecureString 'PASSWORD' -AsPlainText -Force
$LiveCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("username@domain.com", $password)
New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://ps.outlook.com/powershell/ -Credential $LiveCred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection

Connect-MsolService -Credential $Livecred


$userIDs = Import-CSV "c:\Export\list.csv"
$O365Users = Get-MsolUser -All

ForEach ($O365User in $O365Users)
{
  foreach ($userID in $userIDs) 
    {
    $ADuser = Get-ADUser -Filter "EmployeeID -eq $($userID.EmployeeID)" -Properties whenCreated, Enabled, SAMAccountName,ObjectGUID
    $valuetoconvert=$ADuser.ObjectGUID
    $guid = [GUID]$valuetoconvert
    $bytearray = $guid.tobytearray()
    $ImmutableID = [system.convert]::ToBase64String($bytearray)


  If (($ADUser.Enabled -eq $True) -and ($O365User.isLicensed = $true) -and ($ImmutableID -eq $O365User.ImmutableID ) )
    {
        Get-MsolUSer -UserPrincipalName $ADuser.UserPrincipalName
        Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $ADuser.UserPrincipalName -RemoveLicenses "company:ENTERPRISEPACK"
    }

    }   
}
```

Comment: I assuming if statement has "(" missing. But even though I have tried its still not working.

Comment: Unfortunately script still does not returns any data and working for 30 minutes

Comment: @Paul  you are looping through the complete csv for every o365 user which opens you up to possibly needlessly loop through users who aren´t even listed in the csv (apart from the approach itself being very inefficient). so if you have 1000 o365 users and 100 ids in the list you have 100.000 executions of `Get-ADuser` and the rest of the code inside the foreach.